# In TDD, should a CLI menu be tested?

Tags: tdd

I have to create a CLI application following TDD. The app should present a menu of items that can be added to an internal structure, and process those items according some rules.

My question is if I should add a test for the menu, since it would be a string and it will not be opened to change.

Comment: In TDD, how are you adding the menu _without_ a failing test that says you need it?

Answer (score 4):

Using Test Driven Development implies that the test gets written first. So if you have a command line menu with no test, you are not following test driven development for the menu.

There are a couple of ways to look at this question. The first way is "should the menu have a test in TDD" and the answer is "yes, but write the test first." The second way of looking at this question is determining whether or not writing that test is worth your time.

Not every single line of code requires unit tests. Trivial logic does not need to be unit tested. Code that cannot be isolated from its dependencies cannot be properly unit tested either, making integration or functional tests more valuable.

If the menu really is just a static string or constant, the decision to write a unit test for that is subjective. Honestly, the time you spent writing this question (and the time I spent writing this answer) was more time than it would take to write that simple test.

This decision changes if the menu is built using some sort of logic. As soon as non-trivial logic is involved, the test is beneficial. Spend the time to write it.

Answer (score 1):

> The app should present a menu of items that can be added to an internal structure, and process those items according to some rules.

Can we break this into two requirements?

> The app should present a menu that can take input

and

> The app should add items to an internal structure according to some input, and process those items according some rules.

Do that and you can test the more interesting behavior with or without the menu.

That said, sure. You can wrap a CLI menu in a test. Given some input, you expect some output. But spend most of your time testing the more interesting behavior. That's where bugs hide.